# Socket.io with two node apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am serving my main website with express and node.js, this gives me tremendous flexibility with my site.

I also have a back end app which runs on a separate node.js server, I think I may consider just combining it all into one, that strikes up some problems though and I like them being abstracted.

The only real issue I have had is socket.io communication between the two. On the front end site, a user can login/signup to the site and has access to a chat box that has limited features, just limited to a quick chat module.

The user object and any messages are sent to the same DB as the backend app, so the two share the same data, but the real time events don't work as both are loading different client side scripts.

So my question is what should I do to allow the two node.js servers/clients communicate with websocket events?

I tried within my site loading the socket.io script from my app

```
<script src="http://app.example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

for some reason I get

```
// adds :3000 ??
GET http://app.example.com:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1420321032701 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the real time events don't work as both are loading different client side scripts.

I don't think the problem is the client side javascript code, it's the fact that the server instances don't share a common message bus.

> So my question is what should I do to allow the two node.js servers/clients communicate with websocket events?

You need to read the [using multiple nodes](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) section of the docs and set up something like redis to server as the pub/sub central hub.

Comment: Damn okay, looks like I gotta roll up my sleeves lol I hope it's not a pain. Thanks Peter

Comment: Oh I realize its just that small section at the bottom, does not look so bad. I am confused though `io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));` how does this work with the two servers? If I used the pub/sub methods, does that mean my site is the pub and the app is the sub lol?

Comment: Do I need to setup a third server, a redis server? I think this is what this is all about, `site > redis server < app` and `io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));` 6379 is the redis server?